# getting SSM error while migrating spring boot from 2.3.0 to 2.6.1

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, spring-boot

I am migrating spring boot from 2.3.0 to 2.6.1. I am getting "field SSMClient required a bean of type 'com.amazonaws.services.simplesystemsmanagement.AWSSimpleSystemsManagement' that could not be found." error.
Below is the build.gradle file:

```
plugins {
    id 'org.springframework.boot' version '2.6.1'
    id 'io.spring.dependency-management' version '1.0.8.RELEASE'
    id 'java'
}

group = 'com.skechers.loyalty.points'
version = '0.0.1-SNAPSHOT'
sourceCompatibility = '1.8'

configurations {
    developmentOnly
    runtimeClasspath {
        extendsFrom developmentOnly
    }
    compileOnly {
        extendsFrom annotationProcessor
    }
        
    //This is required to enable log4j2
    all {
        exclude group:'org.springframework.boot', module:'spring-boot-starter-logging'
    }
}

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

ext {
    set('springCloudVersion', "2021.0.0")
}

dependencies {

    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-actuator'
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-jpa'
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web'
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-webflux'
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-rest'
    implementation 'org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-starter-aws-parameter-store-config:2.2.6.RELEASE'
    implementation 'org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-starter-aws-messaging:2.2.6.RELEASE'
    implementation 'com.googlecode.json-simple:json-simple:1.1.1'
    implementation 'org.apache.httpcomponents:httpclient:4.4.1'
    implementation 'com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-databind'
    implementation 'com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat:jackson-dataformat-yaml'
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-log4j2'
    implementation 'commons-codec:commons-codec:1.9'
    
    compileOnly 'org.projectlombok:lombok'
    runtimeOnly 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-devtools'
    runtimeOnly 'com.h2database:h2'
    annotationProcessor 'org.projectlombok:lombok'
    testImplementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test'
    testImplementation 'org.springframework:spring-web'
    // required if you want to use Mockito for unit tests
    testCompile 'org.mockito:mockito-core:2.7.22'
}

dependencyManagement {
    imports {
        mavenBom "org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-dependencies:${springCloudVersion}"
    }
}
```

Please guide me on this.
Note : I am not supposed to create bean.